# CSS z-index for an element with fixed parent not working

Tags: css, z-index

Having an issue when an element with relative positioning and a parent with fixed positioning is not being affected by the `z-index` property for some reason.

Everything works fine if I set the parent element to `position:relative;`

```css
.outer {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
.inner {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 5;
}
#example1 .outer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}
#example2 .outer {
  position: fixed;
  top: 150px;
}
.backdrop {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
}
```

```html
<div id="example1">
  <div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">z-index works fine</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="example2">
  <div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">z-index doesn't work</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="backdrop">

</div>
```

Also a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d9uo8z51/1/).

Comment: I think I got it, I am going to delete my answer and add a new one.

Answer (score 0):

...Or just set `z-index:1` on `#example2 .outer` to place it above `.backdrop`

Comment: doesn't fix my issue. the thing is that I need my `.outer` div to be under the backdrop, but the `.inner` should be over backdrop.

Comment: That's not possible, if your `.outer` div is over `.backdrop`, and your `.inner` div is **inside** of your `.outer` div, then logic simply does not allow it to show up behind `.backdrop` - you need to modify your HTML.

Comment: howcome my `.outer` is over `backdrop`? it is having a fixed positioning with the default z-index.

Comment: What are you trying to reach with your final result? You should be more specific.

Comment: I expect to have a `.inner` div to be over my `.backdrop` and with a fixed-positioned parent with a class `.outer`. as you can see from my fiddle, everything works fine for `#example1`, when `.outer` is having a `position:absolute;` property

Comment: @ArsenBatyuchok - you're being unclear. Adding `#example2 .outer { z-index: 1; }` achieves `.inner` being above `.backdrop`

Comment: how can I be more clear than just giving you a jsfiddle ( http://jsfiddle.net/d9uo8z51/1/ ) example? guys, thanks for your tries to help. in my JSfiddle you can see which effect I am trying to reach. there are two cases, one when parent .outer has an absolute positioning, and example 2 has .outer with fixed position. i want my text to be over ALL other elements in BOTH cases, saving a fixed positioning for my .outer parent.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I got your problem. To solve the issue, you have to set a `z-index: 1`. In your case you have to add the following part:

```
#example2 .outer {
    position: fixed;
    top: 150px;
    z-index: 1;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}
```

If you just mess with the `z-index`, the element will look darker. So what you have to do is definining a black background with opacity equal to `.outer - (.outer * .backdrop) = 0.5 - (0.7 * 0.5)`. I can't say this is the simplest solution possible, but I think that as stated also by @Adam, then you have to re-think your code.

This is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2y3u5h16/).

Comment: still not a solution. I created this jsfiddle to demonstrate the problem, in my real page I have a much more complicated layout and design, so your trick with background doesn't solve the real problem, but just fixes it in jsfiddle case.

Comment: @ArsenBatyuchok - what **is** your problem? I explained in my comment below that if you have a parent element that has to be **on top** of `.backdrop`, then any children of that parent also **HAVE** to be on top of `.backdrop`